# Get only a sublist with a lowest value at specific index

Tags: python, list, max, min, nested-lists

I've got a list

```
[[1, 2, 48.5], [1, 3, 66.7], [1, 4, 32.4]]
```

and I want to only get a list with the lowest value at index of 2 so that I only get a list like this

```
[1, 4, 32.4]
```

I have tried messing around with the min() and max() functions but I couldn't figure anything out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and specify in the `key` that you want to order based on the second index:

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = [[1, 2, 48.5], [1, 3, 66.7], [1, 4, 32.4]]
min(l, key=itemgetter(2))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 4, 32.4]
```